# Modularized R markdown structure

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

There are a few questions about this already, but they are either unclear or provide solutions that don't work, perhaps because they are outdated:

- [Proper R Markdown Code Organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822873/proper-r-markdown-code-organization)
- [How to source R Markdown file like `source('myfile.r')`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966109/how-to-source-r-markdown-file-like-sourcemyfile-r)
- http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/

#### Modularized code structure for large projects

R Markdown/Notebook is nice, but the way it's presented, there is typically a single file that has all the text and all the code chunks. I often have projects where such a single file structure is not a good setup. Instead, I use a single `.R` master file that loads the other `.R` files in order. I'd like to replicate this structure using R Notebook i.e. such that I have a single `.Rmd` file that I call the code from multiple `.R` files from.

The nice thing about working with a project this way is that it allows for the nice normal workflow with RStudio using the `.R` files but also the neat output from R Notebook/Markdown without duplicating the code.

#### Minimal example

This is simplified to make the example as small as possible. Two `.R` files and one master `.Rmd` file.

`start.R`

```
# libs --------------------------------------------------------------------
library(pacman)
p_load(dplyr, ggplot2)
#normally load a lot of packages here

# data --------------------------------------------------------------------
d = iris
#use iris for example, but normally would load data from file

# data manipulation tasks -------------------------------------------------
#some code here to extract useful info from the data
setosa = dplyr::filter(d, Species == "setosa")
```

`plot.R`

```
#setosa only
ggplot(setosa, aes(Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_density()

#all together
ggplot(d, aes(Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_density()
```

And then the notebook file:

`notebook.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document: default
  html_notebook: default
---

First we load some packages and data and do slight transformation:

```{r start}
#a command here to load the code from start.R and display it
```

```{r plot}
#a command here to load the code from plot.R and display it
```
````

#### Desired output

The desired output is that which one gets from manually copying over the code from `start.R` and `plot.R` into the code chunks in `notebook.Rmd`. This looks like this (some missing due to lack of screen space):

[image]

### Things I've tried

#### `source`

This loads the code, but does not display it. It just displays the `source` command:

[image]

#### `knitr::read_chunk`

This command was mentioned [here](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/), but actually it does the same as `source` as far as I can tell: it loads the code but displays nothing.

[image]

How do I get the desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to use knitr's chunk option `code`. According to [knitr docs](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/):

> code: (NULL; character) if provided, it will override the code in the
>   current chunk; this allows us to programmatically insert code into the
>   current chunk; e.g. a chunk option code =
>   capture.output(dump('fivenum', '')) will use the source code of the
>   function fivenum to replace the current chunk

No example is provided, however. It sounds like one has to feed it a character vector, so let's try `readLines`:

````
```{r start, code=readLines("start.R")}
```

```{r plot, code=readLines("start.R")}
```
````

This produces the desired output and thus allows for a modularized project structure.

Feeding it a file directly does not work (i.e. `code="start.R"`), but would be a nice enhancement.

Comment: This is great. As I've got a folder structure, I've combined this with the here library, which helps with project folders in RStudio.

Answer (score 2):

For interoperability with R Notebooks, you can use knitr's `read_chunk` method as described above. In a notebook, you must call `read_chunk` in the setup chunk; since you can run notebook chunks in any order, this ensures that the external code will always be available.

Here's a minimal example of using `read_chunk` to bring code from an external R script into a notebook:

**example.Rmd**

````
```{r setup}
knitr::read_chunk("example.R")
```

```{r chunk}
```
````

**example.R**

```
## ---- chunk
1 + 1
```

When you execute the empty chunk in the notebook, code from the external file will be inserted, and the results displayed inline, as though the chunk contained that code.

[image: Notebook Output]

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment above, I use the here library to work with projects in folders:

````r
 ```{ r setup, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='asis'}

library(here) 

insert <- function(filename){
  readLines(here::here("massive_report_folder", filename))
}
```
````

and then each chunk looks like

````
```{ r setup, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, 
        results='asis', code=insert("extra_file.R")}
```
````