# Can I customize an R Markdown report by pulling only some text blocks conditionally from another Rmd file?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I looked at child documents as a possible solution to this, but I don't want to include an entire child document in my parent document. I want to be able to scan the child document for relevant information, and just pull that block of information into the parent document.

For instance, if I'm making reproducible reports on vacationing in whatever location I choose, I want to create a child document that's filled with different sections I could selectively pull information from, like: Beach vacation tips, Mountaineering tips, Cruise tips... So, if I want to generate a report about New Zealand, I would want to search for the heading "Beach vacation tips" in my child document, and pull it into my parent document. But I wouldn't want to include text about beaches if I'm producing a report about Nepal, so I'd want to skip that part of the child document.

Is there any way to do this? Thank you!

I've looked into readLines and child documents, but I can't seem to find code that does exactly what I'm looking for. This post [How to source R Markdown file like `source('myfile.r')`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966109/how-to-source-r-markdown-file-like-sourcemyfile-r) had some functions that I thought might help, but I'm struggling to find a direct solution.

EDIT: I figured out how to use the 'readLines' function to read specific lines from a child document and include them in the parent document. I'll probably use an if/else to pull the exact lines I want from the child document depending on the type of report I'm making. But I'm wondering if, instead of using line numbers, there is a way to search the child document for headings instead.

Child document:

```
# Header

Text blah blah.

Blah blah.

Blah.
```

Parent document:

```
{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
cat(readLines('child.Rmd')[c(13:15)], sep = '\n')
```

Is there a neat way to write, in the parent document, that I want all the text under "# Header" from the child document? Thank you!

Comment: Lacking a more specific example, I suggest that a document scanning another `.md` document using `readLines` just to find a specific _chunk_ is a bad approach: you have to parse chunk delimiters and such, and using regex or other patterns for that is problematic at best. Please explain in a little more detail what you're trying to do, and I suggest providing a small but working example would really help with this. (From your description, it sounds like you're either storing data in `.qmd` files, or you are storing standardized processing in it ... for which I say: write a package.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I'm sorry for the confusion, I think what I'm trying to do is probably simpler than it sounded... I'm very new to Rmd, and appreciate your help. "readLines" did generate what I wanted, but I'd like to search the child document for headings or key words instead, so that the content in the child document can change lines without affecting the output. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract specific chunks from an Rmd file, you can use `knitr::purl`.

I'll start with a "hello world" rmarkdown document:

````
---
title: Hello world
params:
  something: "hello"
---

Intro paragraph.

```{r block1, echo = FALSE}
library(dplyr)
# do something here
out1 <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(disp = sum(disp))
```

Another paragraph.

```{r block2}
out2 <- iris %>%
  count(Species)
out2
```

Something else?

```{r}
head(mtcars)
```
````

Now let's extract the code blocks:

```r
tf <- tempfile()
knitr::purl("quux.Rmd", output=tf)
# processing file: quux.Rmd
#                                                                                                                                                                                   
# output file: /home/r2/tmp/RtmpgcG3Ae/file4aad8216b2ef2
# [1] "/home/r2/tmp/RtmpgcG3Ae/file4aad8216b2ef2"

txt <- readLines(tf)
head(txt)
# [1] "params <-"                                                                                                                                                      
# [2] "list(something = \"hello\")"                                                                                                                                    
# [3] ""                                                                                                                                                               
# [4] "## ----block1, echo = FALSE------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
# [5] "library(dplyr)"                                                                                                                                                 
# [6] "# do something here"
```

From here, if we want to split by block, we an do something like:

```r
blocks <- split(txt, cumsum(grepl("^## ----([^-].*[^-])?-+$", txt)))
blockheaders <- gsub("(^## ----|-+$)", "", lines1) |>
  strsplit(",") |>
  lapply(function(z) {
    if (!length(z)) list("unk", "list()") else {
      list(z[1], paste0("list(", paste(z[-1], collapse = ", "), ")"))
    }
  })
str(blockheaders)
# List of 3
#  $ 1:List of 2
#   ..$ : chr "block1"
#   ..$ : chr "list( echo = FALSE)"
#  $ 2:List of 2
#   ..$ : chr "block-2"
#   ..$ : chr "list()"
#  $ 3:List of 2
#   ..$ : chr "unk"
#   ..$ : chr "list()"

names(blocks) <- c("params", make.unique(sapply(blockheaders, `[[`, 1)))
str(blocks)
# List of 4
#  $ params : chr [1:3] "params <-" "list(something = \"hello\")" ""
#  $ block1 : chr [1:8] "## ----block1, echo = FALSE------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"| __truncated__ "library(dplyr)" "# do something here" "out1 <- mtcars %>%
 " ...
#  $ block-2: chr [1:6] "## ----block-2-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"| __truncated__ "out2 <- iris %>%
 " "  count(Species)" "out2" ...
#  $ unk    : chr [1:3] "## ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"| __truncated__ "head(mtcars)" ""
```

You can choose which block to use based on position, block-names, or finding a pattern in the code. I suggest that if you want unambiguous access to specific blocks, make the block names unique, and/or make a clear parseable comment in each one, such as

````
```{r}
###{Houston}###
mtcars %>% count(cyl)
```
````

If you need them, you can parse and use the params for each block,

```r
params <- lapply(setNames(blockheaders, names(blocks)[-1]), `[[`, 2)
str(params)
# List of 3
#  $ block1 : chr "list( echo = FALSE)"
#  $ block-2: chr "list()"
#  $ unk    : chr "list()"
```

Notes:

- I think the  regex for block determination is good enough to deal with block names, but I haven't checked the legal requirements sufficiently to know if this pattern is foolproof. If your names tend to be alphanumeric, then I think you'll be fine.
- As needed, you can parse the block contents and/or (if you need them) block parameters without too much difficulty, though it will be up to you to ensure all of their prerequisites are met (i.e., objects that may be defined in previous blocks).

  ```r
  ## header/yaml params
  eval(parse(text = blocks[[1]][-1]))
  # $something
  # [1] "hello"

  ## block params
  eval(parse(text = params$block1))
  # $echo
  # [1] FALSE
  eval(parse(text = params$`block-2`))
  # list()

  ## parse block contents
  eval(parse(text = blocks$unk))
  #                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
  # Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
  # Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
  # Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
  # Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
  # Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
  # Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
  ```